# Automating the creation of a SQLite database from a batch file

Tags: shell, sqlite, batch-file, build

On a windows platform I have the following:

- `schema.sql` (contains the sql scripts)
- `sqlite3.exe` (command shell for sqlite -> downloaded from sqlite.org)
- `build.bat`  : A batch file with the line :  `sqlite3.exe -init schema.sql default.db3`

When I run build.bat, the database is created as expected, however, the sqlite shell doesn't automatically terminate. So how would I get the batch file to run and terminate the sqlite command shell automatically?

E.g. output:

```
  C:\Work\X\Database>sqlite3.exe -init schema.sql default.db3  
  -- Loading resources from schema.sql  
  SQLite version 3.7.4  
  Enter ".help" for instructions  
  Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"  
  sqlite>
```

Comment: Can you post the build.bat file?

Comment: the batch file contains the following as its only entry:  sqlite3.exe -init schema.sql default.db3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to call it like that:

```
echo .quit | sqlite3.exe
```

Or put `.quit` in the end of your file.

Comment: echo .quit | sqlite3.exe -init schema.sql default.db3

Comment: This worked for me. Putting .quit at the end of the file did not, though.

Answer (score 4):

It seems (since you haven't shown its contents) that the `bat` file is missing the `exit` statement. You can add it yourself:

```
sqlite3.exe -init schema.sql default.db3 .exit
```

Comment: Please do explain the answer too.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with sqlite3 3.11 (but not with 3.8) and the solution that worked for me was:

```
sqlite3.exe default.db3 < schema.sql
```

And Regis's answer worked fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Andrey. If that doesn't work try adding 'quit' on separate line at the end of your schema.sql

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead:

```
type schema.sql | sqlite3 default.db3
```

Answer (score 0):

Golfing Andrey's answer, you can also run:

```
echo | sqlite3
```

EOF is going to close sqlite3